Error while importing data from Google sheet to Google Slide using Google Apps Script
I am trying to import values from Google Sheets to specific placeholders in Google Slide. Here is the template of the slide. The issue is that it is not replacing some values in placeholders in this slide. Here is the code snippet:
function createOffer() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var slides = SlidesApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1bf-3ypg-lGE9_ju_vCUHeQZj0eWiuFRzxIV_9Ap4eaw/edit#slide=id.g2cece5ff8dd_0_76");
  replacePlaceholdersInSlide(slides, sheet);
}

function replacePlaceholdersInSlide(slides, sheet) {
  var slide = slides.getSlides()[0]; // First slide
  var shapes = slide.getShapes();
  var placeholderValuePairs = {
    "{{C10}}": "C10","{{C19}}": "C19","{{C20}}": "C20","{{C23}}": "C23","{{D19}}": "D19",
    "{{C40}}": "C40"
  };
  replacePlaceholdersInShapes(shapes, placeholderValuePairs, sheet);
}


function replacePlaceholdersInShapes(shapes, placeholderValuePairs, sheet) {

  shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
    if (shape.getText) { 
      var text = shape.getText(); 
      for (var placeholder in placeholderValuePairs) {
        var newValue = sheet.getRange(placeholderValuePairs[placeholder]).getDisplayValue();
        text.replaceAllText(placeholder, newValue);
      }
    }
  });
}

However, I am unable to find an issue as to why it does not replace the following values:
"{{C19}}","{{C20}}","{{C23}}" in the slide. Any guidance to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

Modification points:

About it does not replace the following values: "{{C19}}","{{C20}}","{{C23}}" in the slide, when I saw your provided Google Slides, I noticed that those are included in the group. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.
In your script, getDisplayValue() is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification? In this case, I remembered my answer. So, in this modification, this answer is used in your script.
Modifieid script:
In this case, in order to retrieve values from multiple cells by one API call, Sheets API is used. So, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.
function createOffer() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var placeholderValuePairs = { "{{C10}}": "C10", "{{C19}}": "C19", "{{C20}}": "C20", "{{C23}}": "C23", "{{D19}}": "D19", "{{C40}}": "C40" };
  var presentationUrl = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1bf-3ypg-lGE9_ju_vCUHeQZj0eWiuFRzxIV_9Ap4eaw/edit#slide=id.g2cece5ff8dd_0_76";

  // Create an array object for replacing the texts.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var { keys, ranges } = Object.entries(placeholderValuePairs).reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
    o.keys.push(k);
    o.ranges.push(`'${sheetName}'!${v}`);
    return o;
  }, { keys: [], ranges: [] });
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ss.getId(), { ranges, valueRenderOption: "FORMATTED_VALUE" }).valueRanges;
  var obj = keys.map((k, i) => [k, values[i].values[0][0]]);

  // Retirve 1st slide.
  var slides = SlidesApp.openByUrl(presentationUrl);
  var slide = slides.getSlides()[0]; // First slide

  // Replace texts in the shapes.
  const shapes = slide.getShapes();
  if (shapes.length > 0) {
    shapes.forEach(shape => {
      const text = shape.getText();
      obj.forEach(e => text.replaceAllText(...e));
    });
  }

  // Replace texts in the groups.
  const processGroups = g => {
    g.getChildren().forEach(c => {
      const type = c.getPageElementType();
      if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE) {
        const text = c.asShape().getText();
        obj.forEach(e => text.replaceAllText(...e));
      } else if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.GROUP) {
        processGroups(c.asGroup());
      }
    });
  }
  slide.getGroups().forEach(processGroups);
}


When I tested this script using your provided Google Slide and a sample Spreadsheet, I confirmed that all placeholders could be replaced.

Reference:

Related thread.

How to access shapes inside grouped shapes on Google slides using Apps Script?




Thank you for your answer, it runs successfully on this specific slide. I request your suggestion to generalize the presentationURL variable, as it points to only one specific slide if I want to change the document URL then it throws an error. I want it to run on any slide 1 rather than just one which is mentioned in the variable.

@EagleEye Thank you for replying. From it runs successfully on this specific slide., I understood that your issue was resolved. About your new question of I request your suggestion to generalize the presentationURL variable, as it points to only one specific slide if I want to change the document URL then it throws an error., I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the details of your new question? First, I would like to correctly understand your new question.

@EagleEye From if I want to change the document URL then it throws an error, for example, do you want to use both Google Slides and Google Documents as the template? By the way, var slides = SlidesApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/###/edit#slide=id.g2cece5ff8dd_0_76"); is from your showing script. If this was not your expected result, I have to apologize.

sorry for the confusion, I was able to make it work as per my requirement, I have marked this answer.

The reason why it's not working is in the article Insert and arrange text, shapes, diagrams, and lines.

If you want use multiple objects like a single object, you can group them together.

{{C19}}, {{C20}}, and {{C23}} are currently grouped and are being treated as a single element, which is why the function doesn't work on them.
To resolve this, ungroup them first and run the function again.
